# Action Bar Background size, Android

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I want to change the action bar background color to a custom color. This is what I currently get:

[image]

How do I get this color on the full action bar width?

My action bar `xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="#0c555c"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:paddingStart="0dp"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom">
</RelativeLayout>
```

`onCreate` method:

```
RelativeLayout actionBar = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.action_bar_title);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are designing your custom actionBar than write your code like this:

```
  ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#8B58A3")));

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") 
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.titleview, null);

   actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: What does mean @SuppressLint("InflateParams") ?
Thanks its work!

Comment: Ernis this is passed due to the presence of null that means "When inflating a layout, avoid passing in null as the parent view, since otherwise any layout parameters on the root of the inflated layout will be ignored."

So to ignore this warning we pass @suppressLint as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

please add this line at the end .

Toolbar parent =(Toolbar) actionBar.getParent();
            parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);

Comment: What is view? because i didnt using that

Comment: on your side it is actionBar,where you are influated layout file.

Comment: mhm.. im doing something wrong because when i typed that code in the end i get a new error with java.lang.NullPointerException